# How to use HTTP.call with beforeSend on the client?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Meteor's recent update added an option to the http package to use [beforeSend](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http_call), allowing us to access the xhr object on the client. I am on occasion uploading or downloading large files on the client and I want to have a progress indicator as well as a cancel option. I can not get beforeSend to work, unfortunately.

**Question**

What is the proper way to use beforeSend and/or why does my code not work?

**What Happens**

Http.call runs completely, but my beforeSend function is never executed.

**Relevant Packages**

- Meteor 1.2.1
- http 1.1.1
- aldeed:http

**Relevant Client Code**

```
httpProgress = function(xhr) {
    console.log('I never see this');
    xhr.onprogress = function(e) {
        if (e.lengthComputable) {
            setProgress((e.loaded / e.total) * 100, 'downloading...', true);
        }
        else{
            setProgress(-1, 'downloading...', true);
        }
    };
};
HTTP.call('GET',url, {
        beforeSend: httpProgress,
        headers: {
            'Accept': '*/*'
        },
        responseType: 'arraybuffer' //using aldeed:http here
    }, function(error, result) { 
      ...
    }
);
```

**Meteor's Documentation on beforeSend**

> On the client, this will be called before the request is sent to allow
>   for more direct manipulation of the underlying XMLHttpRequest object,
>   which will be passed as the first argument. If the callback returns
>   false, the request will be not be send.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP.call method in aldeed:http package does not support any beforeSend parameter yet. You can check it in source code [here](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-http-extras/blob/master/http-extras-client.js)

Comment: yup seems like a bug in aldeed:http

Comment: Thank you. I should have thought to check this. I removed the aldeed package and I attempted to use my code, it worked fine. I'll have to modify the aldeed package for now since I need both features.